# Transparently redirect all incoming traffic from wifi hotspot to specific port?

Tags: networking, iptables, wifi-hotspot, iptables-redirect

I am using my laptop as a wifi hotspot to share my internet connection with other devices.

My internet connection goes out through a socks proxy. In my laptop I configured redsocks to redirect all traffic through port 12345 through this socks proxy.

I want all the incoming traffic from the wifi hotspot gets transparently redirected to this port that redsocks is listening to.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is redsocks redirecting all traffic, or is it listening?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec redsocks is listening on a port. I want to redirect the wifi hotspot incoming traffic to this port.

Comment: there are comments for routing at the end of the example: https://github.com/darkk/redsocks#iptables-example